# Create new DF with values representing difference between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with two numeric data.frames, both with 13803obs and 13803 variables. Their col- and rownames are identical however their entries are different. What I want to do is create a new data.frame where I have subtracted df2 values with df1 values. 
"Formula" would be this, `df1(entri-values) - df2(entri-values) = df3` difference. In other words, the purpose is to find the difference between all entries.

My problem illustrated here.

DF1

```
        [GENE128]  [GENE271]  [GENE2983] 
[GENE231] 0.71       0.98       0.32
[GENE128] 0.23       0.61       0.90
[GENE271] 0.87       0.95       0.63
```

DF2

```
        [GENE128]  [GENE271]  [GENE2983] 
[GENE231] 0.70      0.94      0.30
[GENE128] 0.25      0.51      0.80
[GENE271] 0.82      0.92      0.60
```

NEW DF3

```
        [GENE128]  [GENE271]  [GENE2983] 
[GENE231] 0.01      0.04      0.02
[GENE128] -.02      0.10      0.10
[GENE271] 0.05      0.03      0.03
```

So, in DF3 the values are the difference between DF1 and DF2 for each entry.

`DF1(GENE231) - DF2(GENE231) = DF3(DIFFERENCE-GENE231)`

`DF1(GENE271) - DF2(GENE271) = DF3(DIFFERENCE-GENE271)`

and so on...

Help would be much appreciated!

Kind regards,
Harebell